# How to query data if it contains at least one condition [MongoDB]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 4 objects contain days of week as:

```
Obj_1: ['fri','sat','sun'],
Obj_2: ['mon','tue','sun'],
Obj_3: ['wed','sun'],
Obj_4: ['web','sat']
```

When I query with `keyword = 'wed'`, I got `Obj_3 and Obj_4`
When I query with `keyword = 'fri'`, I got `Obj_1`
But I query with array `keyword = ['wed','fri']`, I got empty result. (I'm using $all)
I expect the return will be `Obj_1, Obj_3 and Obj_4`

I'm looking for an operator like `$or`, but it can query with an array of data.
Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: Use the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator `db.collection.find( { keyword: { $in: ['wed','fri'] } } )`

Comment: just read the manual: [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to match a value in an array, use the $in operator.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

> db.collection.find({$or: [{keyword: 'wed'}, {keyword: 'fri'}]})
>
> OR
>
> db.collection.find({keyword: {$in: ['wed','fri']}})